# Translate MariaDB to SQLServer (top n of each table of database)

Tags: sql, sql-server, mariadb

Hello i have this query that i want to do it in SQL SERVER

Thank you

```
MariaDB [northwind]> select group_concat(" SELECT * from northwind.", table_name, ' limit 10' separator ';') answer from information_schema.tables  where table_schema = 'northwind' ; 
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | answer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |  SELECT * from northwind.customers limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.employee_privileges limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.employees limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.inventory_transaction_types limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.inventory_transactions limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.invoices limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.order_details limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.order_details_status limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.orders limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.orders_status limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.orders_tax_status limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.privileges limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.products limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.purchase_order_details limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.purchase_order_status limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.purchase_orders limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.sales_reports limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.shippers limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.strings limit 10; SELECT * from northwind.suppliers limit 10 |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Make some effort to format the query.

Comment: What seems to be the difficulty?

Comment: I can guess what the problem is and has nothing to do with `TOP N`. You get an error. Post it in the question itself. Even if the error is resolved you'll get *another* error - you are asking about TOP 10 not `limit 10`

Comment: BTW STRING_AGG was added to SQL Server 2017. There are a *lot* of questions that ask how to aggregate strings in earlier versions.